# Error in deploying the app in heroku while using the express in the backend

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

Whenever I am trying to deploy my backend in Heroku it is showing me the error that express module not found even though I properly mentioned in the  JSON and this backend was working perfectly fine in my local computer and I tried to find the answer but didn't found out
For the information, I am attaching the log I received from heroku

```
2020-01-03T10:56:44.902383+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-01-03T10:56:47.393235+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-01-03T10:56:47.356183+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-01-03T10:56:47.197595+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-01-03T10:56:47.197645+00:00 app[web.1]: > smart-brain-api@1.0.0 start /app
2020-01-03T10:56:47.197655+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-01-03T10:56:47.197657+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293581+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293586+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293588+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293590+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293595+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293597+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293599+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293623+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293626+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293633+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293635+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293637+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:1:15)
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293639+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293641+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293643+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293644+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293646+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10) {
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293648+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293650+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/server.js' ]
2020-01-03T10:56:47.293652+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-01-03T10:56:47.298875+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-01-03T10:56:47.299147+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-01-03T10:56:47.300153+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! smart-brain-api@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2020-01-03T10:56:47.300313+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-01-03T10:56:47.300484+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-01-03T10:56:47.300625+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the smart-brain-api@1.0.0 start script.
2020-01-03T10:56:47.300757+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-01-03T10:56:47.308098+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-01-03T10:56:47.308217+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-01-03T10:56:47.308312+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-01-03T10_56_47_301Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you added express in your package.json? It seems that npm does not install it.

Comment: I did added the express in my package.json

Answer (score 2):

Did you do `npm install` before running ? From first look, it shows that it cannot find node modules. Check if the node_modules folder has been created. Then restart the server.

Comment: i heard that it install the module automatic module inside the heroku server and as I read from the documentation I removed my all node modules and leave the package.json file

Comment: No. Look for the node_modules folder. If it is not there or if it is empty, do npm install. Maybe some modules are missing or no modules were installed at all. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs use this guide

Comment: I tried all the method given in the documentation and when i run the app by using   the command ```heroku local web``` it worked fine but whenever I am running the same on heroku it is giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem the main issue that I was having with express because in the `package.json` file I mentioned it in the devDependencies instead of putting it in dependencies file and after putting the express in dependencies object it worked well.